# Reactjs - passing same props to multiple child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that have several child components. The props passed for the child components are all the same. For example

```
<TextQuestion questionInfo={this.props.questionInfo} key={this.props.questionInfo.module_question_id} handleChange={this.handleChange} />

<DropDown questionInfo={this.props.questionInfo} key={this.props.questionInfo.module_question_id} handleChange={this.handleChange} />

<Checkbox questionInfo={this.props.questionInfo} key={this.props.questionInfo.module_question_id} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? May be a function call that returns the props and gets added to the child component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const someProps = {
  questionInfo: this.props.questionInfo,
  key: this.props.questionInfo.module_question_id,
  handleChange: this.handleChange,
}

<TextQuestion {...someProps} />
<DropDown {...someProps} />
```

Alternatively, if the components are siblings, you can put them in an array and do a `map`:

```
{[TextQuestion, DropDown, Checkbox].map((Component, i) => <Component key={i} questionInfo={...} />}
```